# How to render a reactjs component stored in a redux reducer?

Tags: reactjs, components, render, store, redux

I have a redux reducer loaded with several reactjs components.

I want to load these inside other components through `this.props`

Like: `this.props.components.MyReactComponent`

```
class OtherComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const Component = this.props.components.MyReactComponent
    return (
      <div>
        <Component />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

**EDIT** The component is a connected component. I am able to load it but it is broken. In this case, it is a counter, when you click to increment or decrement nothing happens. In the console, there is this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _classCallCheck is not defined
```

if I convert the component into a dumb component (without connecting it), the error is this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _classCallCheck3 is not defined
```

**EDIT 2**

I found out why those errors show up. It is because the react component gets stripped out when stored in the reducer:

A react component would look something like this:

```
{ function:
   { [Function: Connect]
     displayName: 'Connect(Counter)',
     WrappedComponent: { [Function: Counter] propTypes: [Object] },
     contextTypes: { store: [Object] },
     propTypes: { store: [Object] } } }
```

However, after I store it inside a reducer, it loses its properties and ends up looking something like this:

```
{ function:
   { [Function: Connect] } }
```

After reading the comments below, I thought of an alternative. I can store in a reducer the path to each component, then make a new wrapper component that could render those other components from those paths.

I tried it but encoutered a different problem with the funcion `require` from nodejs that for some weird reason is not letting me user a variable as an argument. For example:

This works:

```
var SomeContent = require('../extensions/myContent/containers')
```

This does not:

```
var testpath = '../extensions/myContent/containers'
var SomeContent = require(testpath)
```

Giving me the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../extensions/myContent/containers'.
```

It is adding a period at the end of the path. How can I prevent `require` to add that period?

If you can think of any other alternative I can implement for what I am trying to do, I would greatly appreciate it.

**EDIT 3** Following Thomas advice...

What I am trying to accomplish is this:

I want to be able to render react components inside other react components, I know how to do it the same way most us know how to; however, I want to be able to do it by importing a file that would contain all the components  without actually having to import and export each one of them:

OtherComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { SomeComponent } from '../allComponentes/index.js'

export default class OtherComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SomeComponent />
    )
  }
}
```

SomeComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class SomeComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

allComponents/index.js

```
import SomeComponent from '../allComponents/SomeComponent/index.js'

export { SomeComponent }
```

What I am trying to do in `allComponents/index.js` is to avoid having import/export statements for each component by reading (with `fs` module) all the components inside the `allComponents` folder and export them.

allComponents/index.js (pseudocode)

```
get all folders inside allComponents folder
  loop through each folder and require the components
    store each component inside an object

export object
```

When I tried that, I encountered multiple issues, for one, export statements have to be in the top-level, and second, `fs` would work only on the server side.

So, that is why I thought of loading all the components in a reducer and then pass them as props. But as I found out, they got stripped out when stored them in a reducer.

Then, I thought of only storing the path to those components inside a reducer and have a wrapper component that would use that path to `require` the needed component. This method almost worked out but the nodejs function `require` wont allow me to pass a variable as an argument (as shown in EDIT 2)

Comment: Why are you loading/storing components in the reducer?

Comment: @Joe Because I am experimenting and want to load components stored in a reducer. By the way, I can get the component to display but it is broken, I will update my original question to explain this.

Comment: It's just that I had only come across plain json type data objects in stores (which are then operated on in the reducer function), so I was thrown by your question.  Is storing your react component itself in the store not overcomplicating things?

Comment: Agree w. Joe, this seems like overcomplicating it, and definitely not the common use case w. Redux. Here is a quote from the Redux docs (http://rackt.org/redux/docs/basics/Reducers.html): `Given the same arguments, it should calculate the next state and return it. No surprises. No side effects. No API calls. No mutations. Just a calculation`. I'd say it would be much easier for yourself and your app to listen to a value from the Redux store, and based on that render the given component(s).

Comment: @Joe I updated my question, is that the reason of why my components stored in a reducer get stripped out? I am scanning a folder full of components and try to avoid having an index to export each of them. So I want to be able to import them inside other components without the need to export them manually.

Comment: @Thomas I updated my question, could you please elaborate your answer. I am open to alternatives to solve my problem.

Comment: @ElPirru I need more  information about the app and the purpose (what should it be able to do) before I can help you. Forget storing components for this, but rather tell us what is the purpose of the counter and when/why/how should it add/remove/something else a new component (and what does this component do). That way I'd be able to better help you and understand the context. Also please enlighten us in terms of structure of the app (files, directories etc.).

Comment: @Thomas I did my best to explain what I am trying to do, please let me know if my explanation is not clear enough, I will try to improve it.

Comment: @ElPirru Helps a bunch. One question: What do are you trying to gain of not importing/exporting modules, and instead store them in a reducer? Also when you mention the use of `fs`, it seems to me that you're not following a common React setup, see https://github.com/vesparny/react-kickstart for an example. Usually what you would to, is to have a bunch of different components, import them in a wrapper and then render/display them according to different settings within your reducer and potentially add react-router to allow users to route between specific components.

Comment: @Thomas I am trying to do a drop in system that will allow me to drop some files in a folder and it will just work. I already did this for reducers in an universal app and it is working beautifully. I will make it open source so I can let you know when I release it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is not really to do with `redux` but rather is (as you say):

```
What I am trying to do in allComponents/index.js is to avoid having import/export statements for each component by reading (with fs module) all the components inside the allComponents folder and export them.
```

By way of example, I have all of my (dumb) form components in a folder path `components/form-components` and the `index.js` looks something like:

```
export FieldSet from './FieldSet'
export Input from './Input'
export Label from './Label'
export Submit from './Submit'
export Select from './Select'
export Textarea from './Textarea'
```

Then when I want to import a component elsewhere, it is `import { FieldSet, Label, Input, Submit } from '../../components/form-components/';`